Elongating a path in a 2-connected graph
Suppose $G$ is a 2-connected graph, let $u$ and be two vertices in $G$, and suppose there is a cycle $C$ in $G$ of length $\ell$, which does not contain $u$ or $v$.
My goal is to find a long path from $u$ to $v$, at least length $\ell/2$, by going through the cycle $C$:

I am aware of Menger’s theorem, which I suspect could be helpful:

Theorem. A graph is $2$-connected if and only if it contains $2$ internally vertex-disjoint paths between any two vertices.

I'm not sure how to go about this however, since the theorem gives us two vertex-disjoint paths joining $u$ to $v$, but both paths might use parts of the cycle $C$, I'm not sure how I can get the path to look like the red one illustrated above.
